# How to filter the user installed camera application from predefined camera application

Tags: java, android

This is my piece of code

```
Intent cameraintent= new Intent();
cameraintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON);
cameraintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA));
sendOrderedBroadcast(cameraintent, null);
```

But it list out all camera application. I want to filter it. And another issues i need to implement full features of OS dependent camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two primary forms of intents you can use.

**Explicit Intents** have specified a component (via setComponent(ComponentName) or setClass(Context, Class)), which provides the exact class to be run. Often these will not include any other information, simply being a way for an application to launch various internal activities it has as the user interacts with the application.

**Implicit Intents** have not specified a component; instead, they must include enough information for the system to determine which of the available components is best to run for that intent.

So you can use an explicit intent.

```
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.camera", "com.android.camera.CameraButtonIntentReceiver"));
```

That will make sure the intent will be delivered to default Camera application.

Comment: let "me" know or let "you" know? @RED.Skull

Comment: Hey sorry for bad english i was in hurry. Ok I have tested it but its not working in device which as multiple camera applicaiton. Intent cameraintent= new Intent();     cameraintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON);
     cameraintent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.camera", "com.android.camera.CameraButtonIntentReceiver"));
     cameraintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA));
     sendOrderedBroadcast(cameraintent, null);

Comment: Piece of code.... Intent cameraintent= new Intent(); cameraintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON); cameraintent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.camera", "com.android.camera.CameraButtonIntentReceiver")); cameraintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA)); sendOrderedBroadcast(cameraintent, null);

Comment: Try startActivity(intent) not sendBroadcast. @RED.Skull

Comment: Hi Jermaine it shows ForceClose error with device as multiple camera application. But it works fine with device has only system predefined camera application